# URL " http:// <mygisServer>/ArcGIS/rest/service/GPTask/MapServer/jobs/<jobid>" not found in the ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing-service

I am Using ArcGIS Server 10.03 SP3. I created a geoprocessing service in the server which returns a result map service. I successfully created the gp service and map service with same name. I need to display the result in my application using ArcGIS Javascript API v3.3.
The logic works like the sample application  http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/samples/gp_resultmapservice/

I tested the gp service in the REST Web interface and successfully executed.The result map is obtaining after completion of the task.

But when I use it in the JS API front end , the fire bug tool shows success execution of the gp task , but when it executes

```
map.addLayer(gpLayer);
```

the response shows

```
dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript9._jsonpCallback({"currentVersion":10.03,"error":{"code":400,"message":"Unable to complete  operation.","details":["Invalid URL"]}});
```

When I tried the url  http:// /ArcGIS/rest/service/GPTask/MapServer/jobs/

The page not found shows.

When I changed the code with

```
gp.getResultImageLayer(jobinfo.jobId, "output", imageParameters, function (gpLayer) {
 map.addLayer(gpLayer)
});
```

I got  the result .

Can anybody help to find the exact reason? I need to include the service via ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer

Here is the My sample code that Did not work

```
function applyGPTask() {
var gpServiceUrl = "http://localhost/ArcGIS/rest/services/GPTasks/GPServer/GPTask";
gp = new esri.tasks.Geoprocessor(gpServiceUrl);
var params = {
    param1: "SUBDIVID=202",
    param2:"value2",
    param3: "value3"

 };    
  gp.setOutputSpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 });
  gp.submitJob(params, gpJobComplete, gpJobStatus, gpJobFailed);
 }

function gpJobComplete(jobinfo) {    
var mapurl = "http://localhost/ArcGIS/rest/services/GPTasks/MapServer/jobs/" + jobinfo.jobId;
var gpLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(mapurl, {
    "id": "gpoutput",
    "opacity": 0.7
});
    map.addLayer(gpLayer);
 }
```

Comment: You may need to add the 2 complete blocks of code so that we understand what you're doing. It may be a problem with the callback functions.

Comment: I find out the issue. The above program is only work with ArcGIS 10.1 Server ,I think if I upgrade my 10.03 version server  with  10.1 this feature will work

Answer (score 4):

I find out the issue. The above program is only work with ArcGIS 10.1 Server ,I think if I upgrade my 10.03 version server with 10.1 this feature will work